# Обособление оборота добавочного характера в конце предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, скобки, присоединительная-конструкция

Только 1-й вариант корректен?

> Я позавчера нашёл свой телефон (в кармане куртки).

> Я позавчера нашёл свой телефон, в кармане куртки.

> Я позавчера нашёл свой телефон — в кармане куртки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для [присоединительных конструкций](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120) характерны такие варианты:

*Я позавчера нашёл свой телефон, в кармане куртки.

Я позавчера нашёл свой телефон — в кармане куртки.

Я позавчера нашёл свой телефон. В кармане куртки.

Я позавчера нашёл свой телефон... в кармане куртки.*

Вариант со скобками тоже возможен.

[Вставные предложения и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125) (справочник Розенталя)

> **1.** **Скобками** выделяются:
> <...>
> **4)** вставные конструкции, синтаксически связанные с основным предложением, но выделенные из него и носящие присоединительный характер.